# Query not working in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using express.js with mongoose for signup. I use crypto for saving the user's password and am now working on the login section. However, when I post values via postman, I am getting the error `"not exist"` over and over again.

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var User = require('./user.js');
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log("error");
        } else if (!user) {
            console.log("not exist");
        } else if(!user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
            console.log("not valid");
        } else {
            console.log("valid");
        }
    });
    res.send("XYZ");
});
```

Comment: Can you show the sample document? Did you checked what you getting in `req.body.email`? P.S. don't trust the data from client, you always must to filter data which comes from the outside.

Comment: check by console logging req.body.email or use a debugger

Comment: @Amit: req.body.email is working , showing email id in console but still showing "not exist",

Comment: @RichaChawla I highly recommand looking at `manage-users` npm package at: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/manage-users`. DISCLAIMER: I am the author of the module